# AngularJS, Jasmine service testing injection failure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine

I've successfully tested controllers using Jasmine but testing a service seems a bit harder.
The problem is the following: I've no idea how to inject a service in a service test. In a controller I would do the following:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    // Create a new scope that's a child of the $rootScope
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    var storage = {
        add: function (key, value) {

        },
        get: function (key) {
            return "value";
        }
    };

    // Create the controller
    ctrl = $controller('UserCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        localStorageService: storage,
    });
}));
```

I am mocking a local storage service (https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)

When I want to test a service that also uses the localStorageService I get injection errors while running the test.

Service:

```
angular.module('starter.trackingservice', [])
.service('TrackingService', function (localStorageService) { 
         ...
```

Service test:

```
...
var trackingService, storage;

beforeEach(inject(function (TrackingService) {
    trackingService = TrackingService;
}));
...
```

Does somebody know how I can mock a service in a service test, thanks in advance!

Comment: why don't you just inject your service and mock its data?

Comment: I inject the trackingService in its test, but I am having problems injecting the localStorageService in the trackingService test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by doing the following:

```
 beforeEach(function () {

    module("starter.trackingservice", function ($provide) {

        var storage = {
            storVal: false,
            add: function (key, value) {
                storVal = value;
            },
            get: function (key) {
                return storVal;
            }
        };

        $provide.value('localStorageService', storage);
    });

    inject(function (TrackingService) {
        trackingService = TrackingService;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following pattern to test my services:

```
var trackingService;

    beforeEach(module('starter.trackingservice'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (TrackingService) {
            trackingService = TrackingService;
    }));
```

Comment: I've updated my question, the injection of localStorageService within TrackingService is the problem.